# How to determine if a function has singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a rather unusual function and I want to know whether or not it is possible to express it as a infinite power series that converges everywhere. I believe I am correct in thinking that if the function has no singularities, then this is possible. (An assertion which may be wrong). Can anybody suggest any methods of determining whether this function has any singularities. (I suspect it has none but don't know how one could prove this).

$$f(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} {e^{-e^x(x-k)^2}}$$

Comment: The series you have doesn't converge everywhere. Hence I would be surprised if there was an entire function $g$ such that where the series converges, it converges to $g$.

Comment: Where does it diverge?

Comment: $x = \pi i$ for example.